# Intersection point of two moving objects

Tags: systems-of-equations, physics

Suppose we have 2 moving objects along a linear path:

The first object moves at 5 metres/second.

The second object accelerates at 1.5 metres/second.

How would one calculate the point (in time) where both objects have the same position?

Comment: You would need to know the relative position and velocity of the second object at some point to solve.

Comment: Do they both start at the same position, $x=0$?  Acceleration is in distance per time per time, I think you probably mean $m / s^2$

Comment: The second object starts at position 0 and velocity 0. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: So they start at the same place and the second starts with velocity $0$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distance traveled with constant acceleration is given by
$$
d = v_i t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2
$$
where you have $v_i=0$ for the accelerating object.  The distance traveled at constant velocity is
$$
d = vt
$$
So you are looking for $t$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{2}(1.5) t^2 = (5)t
$$

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how to post pictures?

Comment: Hi @AlphaGo.  When you are editing an answer (or question), there is a "image" button in the edit pane, up near the Bold, Italics, etc.  It looks like a mountain range.  When you click it, you can upload or link to images.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I need to sign up and upload the picture to imgur.

Comment: Could this problem be solved using simultaneous equations?

Comment: @MartinRand, oh yes.  That's exactly what I've done above.  You have a distance equation for each object: one for the object accelerating and one for the object with constant velocity.  Then you set those distances equal to each other and solve for $t$.  The graph is the plot of both equations, and its solution is where the curves intersect.

Comment: @Jed, ahhh it never occurred to me that it was a simultaneous equation. I always believed they were solved by re-arranging one equation for x or y and then plugging it in to the second equation.

Comment: @MartinRand oh right, that's how we usually see it in math class.  This is the same mathematically, but with $d$ and $t$ instead of $x$ and $y$.  You could even replace them with $x$ and $y$ and do it that way if you really prefer ;p